# How to update postgres table column based values coming from dataframe using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, sql-update

I have table called Risk which 4 columns.This tables column `risk_state`value needs to be updated with value of `riskState` from Dataframe (DF).

How to write update statement for my uodate query from python. I am not sure how to pass the value from dataframe to Table for updation.

**Risk**

```
risk_id  shipment_id customer_code  risk_state
 125AB     ASW11       JJ           TBW
 326BW     GY456       JJ           TBW
 676BY     ABW11       JJ           TBW
 678BY     BYM11       RR           VT
```

**Dataframe (DF)**

```
riskId   shipmentId customerCode  riskState
 125AB     ASW11       JJ           VT
 326BW     GY456       JJ           VB
 676BY     ABW11       JJ           VT
 678BY     BYM11       RR           VT
```

**Expected Output of Risk Table**

```
risk_id  shipment_id customer_code  risk_state
     125AB     ASW11       JJ           VT
     326BW     GY456       JJ           VB
     676BY     ABW11       JJ           VT
     678BY     BYM11       RR           VT
```

**Code**

#Connection String

```
postgres_str = f'postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'
# Create the connection and cursor
rds_conn = psycopg2.connect(postgres_str)
rds_cur = rds_conn.cursor()
rds_cur.execute("""update risk where...""")
```

rds_conn.commit()

How could this be done...

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in `Postgresql` but I believe what you need is the `merge` function with specific `left_on` and `right_on` arguments:

```py
(risk.merge(Dataframe, 
           left_on=["risk_id", "shipment_id", "customer_code"], 
           right_on=["riskId", "shipmentId", "customerCode"])
            [["risk_id","shipment_id", "customer_code", "riskState"]] 
           .rename(columns={"riskState":"risk_state"}))
```

##### Output

| risk_id | shipment_id | customer_code | risk_state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125AB | ASW11 | JJ | VT |
| 326BW | GY456 | JJ | VB |
| 676BY | ABW11 | JJ | VT |
| 678BY | BYM11 | RR | VT |

I guess you can use this output to update your SQL database.

Comment: I need update the table . What I need is update statement  for the table

Comment: @aeapen So no `pandas` dataframe is required for your question, right?

Comment: @aeapen you can write the output dataframe, as suggested here to a temporary postgres table using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html
and then run your usual `SQL` update query.

Comment: @Amirhossein, Yes . I need to update the table using dataframe value

Comment: @Afaq, Can show me a sample